# Accessing historical data from the U.S. Census of Manufacturers

Tags: data-request, usa, economics, historical

I am looking for historical data from the U.S. Census of Manufacturers for the period from 1945 to today, and ideally even for the period before 1945. On [this website](http://guides.library.pdx.edu/c.php?g=271190&p=1811786#m47), I found out that such data does exist - at least from 1947 onwards. However, because the original reports were published as books (see [this one](https://books.google.ch/books?id=fF2W1JAgYnMC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=census%20us%20manufacturers%201947&source=bl&ots=xTJr9erL-P&sig=011HgXNiIz23ZArn6s0y-nqUfo4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFwoWigeXSAhXLHpoKHUaoB3o4ChDoAQgeMAE#v=onepage&q=census%20us%20manufacturers%201947&f=false), for example) I am not sure whether the historical data was digitized at some point and if it is available.

Can I download the data somewhere? (If so, where?) Or will I need to go to a library and digitize everything myself?

Comment: There is a "Plain Text" option in the settings menu of the link you provided.  You could download the plain text and clean up the bits that you want.

Comment: Thank you, @Edmund. In which of the links? Do you mean the google books one?

Comment: Correct. In the Google Books link.

Comment: Good point. Still, I am wondering whether any of the data related to the reports (not only the 1947 one, not only volume 2) is systematically ordered in some archive. Possibly even already in the form of a .csv or similar.